# what is the exact use of that %value% symbol in the above statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i have come across % symbol in mysql. here is my mysql_query statement.

```
SELECT `permAddr`, `Name` FROM `persons` WHERE `idCardNo` LIKE '%".$_POST['value']."%' LIMIT 1
```

my question now is what is the exact use of that symbol in the above statement. isnt it the modulus symbol ? ? ? any one have the answer ?

Comment: If the `$_POST['value'] = 'cat'`, then the query will find entries like: `cat`, `mycat`, `cats`, `mycats` ... etc

Comment: One thing not directly related to the question: This code will be a nice vector for SQL injections. Let's say the value is something along the lines of ' and (delete from persons) and '

Comment: It means you need to read up on the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) because whomever wrote this has no idea how to properly escape their SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used with `LIKE` it means it's being used as a wildcard. This means that it will match anything whenever the `%` is visible in the query.

For example, if `$_POST['value']` was `bird`, that query would return rows where `idCardNo` matched `bluebird` and `birdhouse`.

You can read more about this operator and others here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Slightly off topic but relevant none the less is that your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should look to use [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php) in your projects.

Answer (score 2):

It's a wildcard that when used with `LIKE` will match any number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

More about: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html